# Error CS0019: Operator * cannot be applied to operands of types 'Vector3' and 'Vector3

Tags: c#, vector, transform

Hi i am trying to move a unity gameobject forward with this script but keep running into a Error CS0019: Operator * cannot be applied to operands of types '.Vector3' and 'Vector3'. why is this I dont understand it.

My code is:

```
 transform.Translate (Vector3.forward * Time.deltaTime * (transform.localScale * 05f));
```

Comment: Because [there is no Vector3 * Vector3 operator](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3-operator_multiply.html)

Answer (score 1):

According to [this](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.html), Vector3 has one overload for operator*, which takes a float as the other parameter (I.e., you can only multiply a Vector3 by a scalar) The operation returns another Vector3.

`Transform.localScale` also returns a Vector3, and multiplying it by 0.5f again returns a Vector3. Which means your code is attempting to multiply two Vector3s, which it can't do.

Perhaps you want:

```
transform.Translate (Vector3.forward.Scale(transform.localScale * 0.5f) * Time.deltaTime);
```

Comment: This does answer the question, but adding at least one of the two known options (multiply their values or call Scale) should be added to be a more complete answer

Comment: ahhh so just add the direction .x to my local scale and its sorted so.

Comment: yup that worked: transform.localScale.x * .05f

Comment: @pete800 `forward` is 1 in the Z direction, isn't it? Might matter if your scales are different for each axis.

Comment: cheers yes i actually had my axis flipped in unity so Ive ended up using localscale.y