# error code CS1061 operator '*' con't be applied to operands of type 'Vector 3' and 'Vector3'. How do I sort this out

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Hi I'm trying to create movement in unity for a character based on velocity with my script but the error
***CS0019   Operator '*' cannot be applied to operands of type 'Vector3' and 'Vector3'*** keeps coming up. I've tried the solution of a similar question,   [Error CS0019: Operator * cannot be applied to operands of types 'Vector3' and 'Vector3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54700966/error-cs0019-operator-cannot-be-applied-to-operands-of-types-vector3-and-v)  but it doesn't work.

here's my code(velocity is a vector3):

rb.MovePosition(rb.position * velocity * Time.fixedDeltaTime);

Comment: Why would you multiply vector3's? I'm **not** into unity, but have seen some libraries offering a static multiply function.  `v3 = Vector3.Multiply(v1, v2);`?

Comment: Can you [edit] question to clarify what you expect as result of the vector multiplication? Based on method you trying to call it looks like you expect vector as result... while by default one would expect scalar multiplication...

Comment: `Vector 3` has a whitespace more then `Vector3` If that was copied, something is wierd...

Comment: Shouldn't you multiply the time by the velocity to get the distance to add to the starting position?  Basically `rb.MovePosition(rb.position + (velocity * Time.fixedDeltaTime));`

Comment: Jeroen is right, you cannot multiply vectors in Unity like that.

Answer (score 1):

To move the rigidbody by velocity, instead of your

```
rb.MovePosition(rb.position * velocity * Time.fixedDeltaTime);
```

try use

```
rb.MovePosition(rb.position + velocity * Time.fixedDeltaTime);
```

Note you can also move a rigidbody via `AddForce()`. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks this really helped.